# Installing 12.10 themes! I can't get any to work

Tags: themes

I cannot seem to get any themes or tweaks to activate or show up in the appearance tab in system settings.  I have downloaded gnome tweak tool and compiz through the terminal, but still nothing.  I have gnome 3.6 also installed.  My question is, when you download a .tar.gz , how do you tell it where to extract to and after it's extrated, THEN what do you do?  This is so confusing.  I'm new to ubuntu and anything non Windows...finally broke the spell....so far, I am absolutely in love with it, but I need help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gnome 3.6 features a new theming engine that is different from 3.4, 3.2, and 3.0. As Gnome 3.6 is relatively new, make sure that the theme is 3.6 compatible first.

After you have verified that it is compatible, extract the zip to your .themes folder in your home folder. If you don't have a .themes folder, make it. To view hidden files in nautilus, use Ctrl + H.

Then, you can apply the theme using a program called the gnome-tweak-tool. To install it, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After it has been installed, you can find it in the activities drawer of Gnome by searching for "Tweak Tool."

Comment: Thank you, it worked.  I have been struggling with this for days now....unfortunately my indecision bug will catch up with me and eventually I will be switching themes over and over again.  What about extensions? Do they work in a similar fashion?

Comment: Extensions are even easier. Just visit https://extensions.gnome.org/ and find an extension you like. Open the page for it and slide the OFF switch to ON.